# Android: Write to file in a non-Activity class

Tags: android, file-io, compiler-errors

How do I open and write to a file in an Android class outside an activity?

`FileWriter` is my external class, initialized from `MainActivity`. The following line in `FileWriter`:

```java
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Yields this compilation error:

```
The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type FileWriter
```

I guess that the class requires some application context - how do I pass it?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095610/android-fileinputstream-read-txt-file-to-string/9095689#comment16807274_9095689 question's answer and comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass a `Context` object to the `FileWriter` class and change your call to this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does this look on the caller's end? Which context object should I pass?

Comment: @AdamMatan, If you're initializing FileWriter from the MainActivity, then FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(this); will do the job.

Comment: Possible solution is to state the name of the class, `FileWriter fw =  new FileWriter(YourClass.this)` or `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(getApplicationContext());`