# Files Don't Hold Enough Characters?

Tags: java, android, file

I'm writing this notepad app where the user types in what they want into an `EditText`, it will `write` that to a file, and then later they can `read` it in a `TextView`.

Here is my `XML` code for the EditText I'm using:

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtWrite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnLogOut"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAppendd"
    android:ems="5"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="2147483646" />
```

The `max length` line was my attempt to fix it, seeing as I thought that would be plenty for the user to `input`. However, it doesn't work.

When I display the `length` of the file, it says that it is 1024, which makes sense, considering how I `input` data from my files:

```
try {
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[1024];
    FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("txt");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
    isr.read(inputBuffer);
    String data = new String(inputBuffer);
    isr.close(); fIn.close();
    display.setText(data + '\n' + '\n' + data.length()); // data + 1024
}catch(Exception e){}
```

That is how I input all of my files (Googled), and so I assume the `new char[1024]` is the reason the `max length` of the file can only be 1024.

Does anyone know another way of inputting files with limitless length? I don't even know why that has to be `new char[1024]`.

Here is how I `write` to files, which is nice because it's short code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(...);
fos.close();
```

Here is my full `write` method:

```
public void write()
{
    Button write = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWrite);
    write.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText writeText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtWrite);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(writeText.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just change this size, I doublt it will not work, put something like 5120 for example.

Comment: I'm hoping for a way to make it as large as possible because I don't want to just put in an arbitrary number. 2147483646 doesn't work.

Comment: @g00dy That would use a lot more memory than necessary and you still can't read anything above that amount.

Comment: @mikeyaworski - with the current implementation, this isn't possible, you're reading 1024 at a time, you can't read "unspeficied" length chars at a time.

Comment: Maybe you can count the characters in the file you're opening before the actual opening and set the char array accordingly (http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/character_stream_reader.shtml): `public int countASCIILetters(File f) throws IOException {
  Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          new FileInputStream(f), "US-ASCII"));
  try {
    int count = 0;
    int intch;
    while ((intch = r.read()) != -1) {
      int ch = (char) intch;
      if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  } finally {
    r.close();
  }
}` -like that?

Comment: @g00dy doesn't work. the `return` `int` from the method is 910, so it only reads the first 910 chars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this:

```
char[] inputBuffer = new char[1024];
FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
isr.read(inputBuffer);
String data = new String(inputBuffer);
```

With this:

```
FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

char[] buffer = new char[1024];
int len;
while ((len = isr.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    fileContent.append(new String(buffer, 0, len));
}

String data = fileContent.toString();
//be sure to call isr.close() and fIn.close()
```

Borrowed in part from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9095689/1132959)

Comment: Basically, you (@Mike) were only reading that buffer full once.  You need to have a loop and keep reading the buffer until you've read the whole file.

Comment: ^ that makes a lot of sense (not sarcastic)

Comment: @mikeyaworski How big is the file?

Comment: @mikeyaworski That may be all that you have in the file is 2048. Verify the file size and that your write code is correct(if testing against that)

Comment: @mikeyaworski Can you post your full write code in your question? You should really use a file browser or something to check the file size.

Comment: It can't be my `writing` because when I switch the `char[1024]` to `char[5120]`, just as a test, it does display my entire file. I didn't even write the file again, I just changed the size of the `char` and read it again and got the full thing. The problem with writing 5120 is that I can't get anything more than that. But I will post my full write method anyways.

Comment: There's a potentially serious bug in this code.  You're reading 1024 bytes at a time and assuming they can be converted to a string using the default character set, but the default character set (on Android) is UTF8, which is a variable-length encoding.  If the 1024th byte of a file is the start of a two-byte character (or the first or second byte of a three-byte character, or so on) this will cause the character to be replaced with a marker character that indicates an encoding error.  Then the next buffer start will be out of sequence, so some characters at the start of that will be lost too.

Comment: To fix the above bug, I'd use the InputStreamReader as the original questioner was doing, and create the string from a char[] rather than the byte[] used here.  This shifts that (actually surprisingly difficult) task of working out where you can stop reading onto the system rather than trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only works if there are 1024 or less characters, meaning that it does not work properly. The idea behind

```
char[] inputBuffer = new char[1024];
```

is that you read into the inputBuffer by 1024-sized chunks, you do this until the read functions returns -1 (EOF is reached).