# Android - Download and store JSON so APP can work offline

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, storage, offline

fellow developers.

I am a junior Android Developer who recently came out of school. I need to develop an application that displays a ListView with some content downloaded from the Internet. The thing is, the JSON is a little bit "big", therefore, it would be good that users could download the JSON with WiFi, and in case that their network connection is bad, they could use a "local copy" of the data instead of having to download it again with slow Internet.

Is there any way I can download JSON-encoded information with AsyncTask or anything and store it locally so I can open it later and load the ListView content again?

Thank you :)

Comment: Many ways.. store the data on a database, write the data into file using FileInputOutputStream, sharedpreferences  and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: [Read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to know what kind of options you have.

Now to answer your question on how to save data on locally some code from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal):

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String yourJSON = downloadedJSON.toString() // depends what kind of lib you are using

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(yourJSON.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Store the FILENAME in the `SharedPreferences` so that you can read it later in case it changes or just to learn how to store data in `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); // PREFS_NAME should be a static final String property
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("myFileName", FILENAME).commit();
```

Then when you reopen the app later you can do it like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String FILENAME = setting.getString("myFileName", "");
if (!FILENAME.isEmpty()) {
   readFile(FILENAME);
}
```

And finally read the file back as `String` from [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095610/android-fileinputstream-read-txt-file-to-string)

```
FileInputStream fis;
fis = openFileInput("test.txt");
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
  fileContent.append(new String(buffer, 0, n)); 
}
```

Try to understand each block of code before you use this code. Go through the Android Documentation and use Google if you are stuck. [Plenty of tutorials out there](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html). Data Storage is fundamental and not just for Android!

Comment: Thank you very much, ezCoding. I'll check everything out today when I come out from work :)

Comment: Arf, I still have not been able to test this, but I will accept the answer as soon as I can test it and see if it works (which I hope it will). Sorry for the delayed answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library :

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

this library support GET/POST method to request and recieve respone from your service.

After that you can save your data by SQLite or android preferences :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm