# Convert a pdf to String in android

Tags: android

I was using the following function to convert a pdf to string:

```
        private String GetString(String filepath) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        String inputStreamToString = inputStream.toString();
        byte[] byteArray = inputStreamToString.getBytes();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encoded;
    }
```

I got the output as:

```
amF2YS5pby5GaWxlSW5wdXRTdHJlYW1ANTM1MDhmNTg=
```

I have found that this output is wrong. Because certainly when I encode a 2MB pdf file, it can't be so short. Actually I base64 decoded in php server and the output was an invalid pdf. So my question is what is missing in the function?

Ok. Problem solved. The following is the correct code to do this:

```
private String GetString(String filepath) throws IOException {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return encoded;
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong? Do you know the right result? Finally, what you want to do?

Comment: Maybe you have to use a different encoding? UTF-8? Has to be the same as the pdf was saved with.

Comment: U see if u convert a 2MB pdf file to string, can this be this short and so small? Moreover I base64 decoded in php server and the output was an invalid pdf... So in this way i know that the output is wrong. @Sergey Glotov

Comment: Can resolve symbol IOUtils in Android Studio 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Wrong part is: `String inputStreamToString = inputStream.toString();`. You'll not get the content of input stream as result, you'll get only something like "FileInputStream@021849".

You should read from stream in another way, e.g.: [Android FileInputStream read() txt file to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095610/)

BTW, instead of reading file to String and converting it to byte array, you can read file straight to byte array.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it with the second code.
But "IOUtils" where the function code .